# CPU Replacement on 2008 Macbook

Tags: cpu, macbook, soldering

I have an old 2008 Unibody Macbook, solely running Elementary OS, currently running an Intel Duo 2 P7350. Recently, I came across an Intel Quad 2 Q6600. I was wondering if, since the processors are in the same family I would be able to replace the current processor with the Quad. I have done some preliminary research, and I know this is a bad idea; however, this is not my main computer, and I would like to try anyway. My method of approach would be as follows:

1. Remove the logic board from the chassis.
2. Remove the heat sink from the CPU.
3. Use a hot air gun to desolder the CPU from the boarder.
4. Solder each pin of the new CPU.
5. Place the CPU in the correct orientation on the board.
6. Use the heat gun to solder the new CPU to the logic board.
7. Reassemble the computer.

Here are the questions I have:

1. Is there anything wrong with the process above? Are there any improvements that could be made?
2. Will my BIOS/EFI support the upgrade, and if not, what would the next steps be?
3. I understand the Quad has four times the maximum load power dissipation of the Duo. Is there anything I can do to manage improve heat dissipation?
4. Is there anything else I am missing?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Your cpu was designed to be removed from its socket.  An air gun isn’t designed to remove a 1000+ pin device

Comment: Thank you for your response. Are you sure the 2008 Macbook has a socket removable CPU? My initial research indicated no. Also, while I am aware that using an air gun is far from ideal, given that it is the only viable tool that I have, is it impossible to desolder the CPU with the air gun, or is it just infeasible? The latter I can deal with.

Comment: I actually meant it was NOT designed to be removed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better if you forget it ASAP.

At the movement when you use airgun to desolder the old cpu you will 
kill the motherboard. "BGA station", google for it, worth it.

Your cpu package is BGA479, Q6600 only available in LGA775. Different
pin count, pin layout, different voltages, different size, different 
everything...

You can replace the CPU only with matching package (in your case is
BGA479), if your motherboard supports the new type. Also you need to
use BGA station for it, because airgun is only good for kill your board.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't consider the CPU package. Hypothetically, in the case of the motherboard, would it be possible if I insulated the area around the CPU, or would the air gun damage the chip and the area underneath it?

Comment: Hypothetically, there's lot of tools (like heat reflector tape/foil) which prevent kill of your board. But I think your airgun is quite simple, no temperature/airflow control. I have a hot air rework station, I could remove the cpu with some other tools (like the heat reflector tape), but with this station it better if I not try to solder another CPU. Resoldering BGA only way is the BGA station.

Comment: You will NOT be able to remove your CPU and install a CPU with an air gun, and have a functioning system, your plan will not work

Comment: Replacing such a CPU requires the proper equipment and the considerable knowledge and skill to use it. A heat gun is a quick and easy way to ruin a circuit board but not much good for anything else. The heat required to damage a CPU is much less than that required to melt solder.  I have plenty of experience replacing smaller ICs, on the order of about 100 pins, enough to know I would never attempt what you are proposing.